# Ignore some TR nodes

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have a HTML like

```
<body>
<tr class="sysinfoTableCategoryHeader">
    <td colspan="4">Operating System</td>
</tr>

    <tr class="sysinfoTablePropertyEven">
        <td />
        <td />
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyKey">Operating System Name</span></td>
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyValue">Linux</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="sysinfoTablePropertyOdd">
        <td />
        <td />
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyKey">Kernel Version</span></td>
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyValue">4.8.0-1-amd64</span></td>
    </tr>

<tr class="sysinfoTableCategoryHeader">
    <td colspan="4">Motherboard</td>
</tr>

    <tr class="sysinfoTablePropertyEven">
        <td />
        <td />
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyKey">Manufacturer</span></td>
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyValue">Acer</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="sysinfoTablePropertyOdd">
        <td />
        <td />
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyKey">Product</span></td>
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyValue">Aspire E5-531</span></td>
    </tr>
</body>
```

So I'm able to pick entire body from this html file which is actually awesome. But there is one problem . Lets say from that body i want to ignore the node with `class` `name="sysinfoTableCategoryHeader"` Operating system.

Is this doable at all ?

My output should be like this

```
<body>
<tr class="sysinfoTableCategoryHeader">
    <td colspan="4">Motherboard</td>
</tr>

    <tr class="sysinfoTablePropertyEven">
        <td />
        <td />
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyKey">Manufacturer</span></td>
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyValue">Acer</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="sysinfoTablePropertyOdd">
        <td />
        <td />
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyKey">Product</span></td>
        <td><span class="sysinfoTablePropertyValue">Aspire E5-531</span></td>
    </tr>
</body>
```

How can i acoomplish it with `HTMLAGILITYPACK` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm english a little. 
exp code:

```
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument(); 
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(your html code); 
HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/tr[@class!='sysinfoTableCategoryHeader']");
```

the htmlNodes is you needs. 
Or use RemoveAllIDforNode();

```
    HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/tr[@class='sysinfoTableCategoryHeader']"); 

foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlNodes) {
 htmlDoc.DocumentNode.RemoveAllIDforNode(node); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need find xpath //tr[@class!='sysinfoTableCategoryHeader']
the xpath have operator.

Comment: Pang can you be more specific i dont understand it sorry